# aligning an unordered list next to a paragraph tag

Tags: html, css

I have a section on my website that i want to look like this:

Wins:  1 | 2 | 5 | 6

Lose:  3 | 5 | 5

I set my mark-up like so:

```
<article class="result_day">
    <p class="win_lose_text">Date: 21/02/2012</p>
        <p class="win_lose_text">Wins: </p>
            <ul>
                <li>1</li>
                <li>1</li>
                <li>1</li>
            </ul>
        <p>lose: </p>
            <ul>
                <li>1</li>
                <li>1</li>
                <li>1</li>
            </ul>
</article>
```

I tried putting the unordered list into the paragraph tag but they later researched that this can't be done. this is my css for the container:

```
.result_day
{
    background: rgba(70,70,70,0.3);
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #333333;
    border-radius: 1px;
}

.result_day ul
{
    list-style-type: none;
}

.result_day li
{
    display: inline;
}
```

My unodered list is always on a new line, i want to be able to keep it on the same line as the paragraph tag. Is there a way of doing this? Maybe there is a way in CSS to stop the

tag from starting a new line?

thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply `display: inline` to *both* your `ul` and your `li`. See this fiddle as an example: http://jsfiddle.net/3nLG5/.

Comment: I think I understood your question properly but if I didn't don't hesitate to correct me.

Comment: That works on you js fiddle, but i doesn't seem to work for me in my code. Also you take away the <p> tags for it to work and i wanted to keep the <p> tags in because it's semantic. Any ideas?

Comment: Hold the phone..... Auto fill thought i wanted inherit not inline. So now they're both inline they both work (This is without the <p> Tags)

Comment: So I answered your question? :)

Comment: Note that a `<p>` tag will by default create a new line after it. That is what a paragraph is supposed to look like, after all. Scrap the `<p>` (it isn't a paragraph anyways) and use something better suited like a `<div>` which encapsulates the element or perhaps one of the new semantic elements found in HTML5 if you are going for the latest and greatest depending on your page architecture.

Comment: Well now my question has been answered. Thanks buddy.